# Matching multiple floats in an IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to match floats that are parsed, with floats from my DB.

```
INFO:root:Sell website: 61.8 - Sell DB: 61.800000
INFO:root:Buy website: 61.35 - Buy DB: 61.350000
INFO:root:Middle website: 61.4905 - Middle DB: 61.490500
```

This is my condition, but it clearly doesn't work.

```
if (sell == row['sell'] and buy == row['buy'] and middle == row['middle']):
    logging.info('No change in rate.')
else:
    logging.info('New rate found!')
```

The numbers are the same, except for the zeros...

Why is python not matching this?